# Issue with AppCompat

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

AppCompat and other tools (date, transitions, etc.) are not visible in the palette. How can I make them appear in my palette?

I'm new to Android Studio, so please help me out. Here is the screen shot of my palette:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this Android Studio doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#layout_editor), the palette has been redesigned in Android 3.1. Also, [this](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/193-android/11668-android-studio-31-released-widgets-lost.html) article states the following:

> The Layout Editor has had some minor changes to the organization of the pallete and this could be a bigger problem. The reorganization may cause some temporary problems finding widgets that you used to know the location of, but this soon passes. More important is the apparent fact that some of you old favorites might well be missing. There is a new "Legacy" section and the "Advanced" section has gone. Along with it the NumberPicker, DataPicker, TimePicker, TextClock, Chronometer and, as far as I can see, the Transistions category has gone completely along with all its widgets.

Also in the same article:

> If you rely on any of the missing Widgets the my advice is don't upgrade until a workaround has been made available. There is no word from the Android Studio team as to why these widgets have been removed and no word on how to put them back.